# I want to change the 404 page title of a wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress

I have a website that uses worpdress with [catch box  theme](https://wordpress.org/themes/catch-box/), and I want to change the 404 page title.
I looked for the "Nothing found for" sentence on the PHP files on the Editor but I did not find nothing.

I searched for the get_header(); method in editor to change the title but I did not find it.

see the title that I want to change
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have been already answered here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30873/how-to-change-404-page-title

**Add the following to theme `functions.php` file**

```
function theme_slug_filter_wp_title( $title ) {
    if ( is_404() ) {
        $title = 'ADD 404 TITLE TEXT HERE';
    }
    // You can do other filtering here, or
    // just return $title
    return $title;
}
// Hook into wp_title filter hook
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'theme_slug_filter_wp_title' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter hook

```
function theme_slug_filter_wp_title( $title ) {
 if ( is_404() ) {
    $title = 'ADD 404 TEXT HERE';
 }
return $title;
}
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'theme_slug_filter_wp_title' );
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one for wordpress **version 4.4+**

file : **function.php**

```php
function theme_slug_filter_wp_title($title_parts)
{
    if (is_404()) {
        $title_parts['title'] = 'My Custom Title Text';
    }

    return $title_parts;
}
add_filter('document_title_parts', 'theme_slug_filter_wp_title');
```